# I can't connect with ssh after restarting

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm new in linux operative systems and I working with the ssh commands to connect with my personal server with Ubuntu.

I have a doubt. When I restart my Ubuntu server and I want try to connect with shh but always says "Cant connect with this network". Then I go physically to the server, connect a keyboard, introduce the user login, go to the terminal and restart de service ssh and then I can now connect with ssh..

The only that I did it's execute is this and works very well

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

But I don't want to go always physically to the server and introduce the user, etc...

What I did for the moment? I created a script in /home/ that check if the service is running or not and then restat or start it. After, I went to

```
sudo visudo
```

And add a line in the bottom

```
userName ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/userName/script.sh
```

To prevent write the root password. And then, in the startup service I included this script. This works, the scripts was executed but I can't connect anyway via ssh.

Somebody help me?

Many thanks

Comment: When this happens? after rebooting the server? are you sure the SSH daemon is enabled?

Comment: Yes, after rebooting the server. And I think that the daemon it's running

   $ ps -A | grep sshd
 1858 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 1883 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 1935 ?        00:00:00 sshd